# OpenVPN-Connection as default gateway for another host in the same subnet

Tags: iptables, openvpn, gateway

I would like to achieve to use my openvpn-connection as default gateway for another host in the same subnet. I have 2 Hosts in the same subnet, both of them with Ubuntu Server 14.04.

**Host A** runs OpenVPN in order to establish a connection to my openvpn-exit-node. This host has been modified in order to allow ip-forwarding.

**Host B** is a client-app-server and should use the internet-connection through the shared openvn-connection from Host A.
As I've setup the gateway-ip of Host B to the IP of Host A, the traffic from Host B now is routed through the openvpn-connection of Host A.

The problem appears as the openvpn-connection on Host A drops (at least every 24hours here in Germany) and reconnects; afterwards Host B uses the default gw from Host A and bypass the openvpn-connection (sometimes until the tunnel is up again and everytime Host B reboots).

The achievement should be, to ensure that Host B gets internet only through the openvpn-connection.
Is there any possibility to ensure, that Host B only has access to the internet as long as it uses the openvn-tunnel?

Host A (eth0 ip:10.11.12.6/gw:10.11.12.1) (tun0 ip:10.8.0.146/gw:10.8.0.145):

- Installed OpenVPN and configured the client-connection to my openvn-exit-node: works
- Configured Host A in order to allow ip-forwarding and configured  IP Masquerading: works

Host B (eth0 ip:10.11.12.9/gw:10.11.12.6):
- Changed the default gateway to the ip-address of Host A: works
- All traffic uses the openvpn-tunnel on Host A

**Problem:**
Everytime the openvpn-connection drops and/or openvpn reconnects, Host B seems to switch back using the default gateway of Host A. Host B in such a moment should remain without internet-access but instead its using the connection Host A uses to connect to the openvpn-gateway.

Kind regards,
D0C

Answer (score 0):

To Achieve this you should use Policy Based Routing; Will allow you create separate independent routing tables, and direct traffic to any routing table based on packet properties like Source-IP.

Create new routing table as follow:

```
echo "200    OpenVPN" >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Add default gateway to the newly created table as follow:

```
route add default via OpenVPN-GW-IP table OpenVPN
```

Allow Host-B to be routed using this routing table:

```
ip rule add from Host-B-IP table OpenVPN
```

You also need to add the following routes to the new table:

```
ip route add 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table OpenVPN
ip route add YOUR-Local-Subnet dev DEVICE-NAME table OpenVPN
```

Update:
Use SNAT instead of MASQURADE,

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.11.12.9 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.146
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help; as the ip-address of my openvpn-connection changes from time to time (dhcp from the vpn-service-provider) I'm not sure about which ip is meant with "OpenVPN-GW-IP".
Thank you and kind regards,
D0C

Comment: I thought you have your own openvpn server, any way OpenVPN-GW-IP: when you are connected to the VPN, your routing table should be changed with new entries added; find out what is the VPN connection gateway,  route -n | grep tun  and use that ip... this should not be changed as i know VPN IPs are assinged based on the certificate and they do not changed by time ...

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding - I've didn't mean that I'm the owner of the VPN-Exit-Node; in fact it's a commercial anonymous vpn-provider (there is now certificate in order to identificate but username/password). Even if the ip-address itself changes, the openvpn-gw-ip should always keep the same - I'm gonna test this and let you know.

Kind regards,
D0C

P.S: added the used adresses in the question

Comment: OK, I've done this now
The traffic from Host B (after a fresh reboot) goes through the openvpn-connection, but the problem persists. If the openvpn-connection drops (tested by manually restarting the openvpn service), Host B switches to the default gateway of my LAN which should be avoided. Even after the re-up of the vpn-tunnel Host B won't reset to the tunnel-gw. The reset happens only after a restart of the Host B.

Kind regards,
D0C

Comment: How Come, what is the relation between HostB and the VPN-Restart, the GW of HostB should be set in static way to the local ip of HostA which is a VPN-Client,   why would restarting the VPN change the GW of HostB ,, this does not make sense..

Comment: ReHi, I've tried to be more clear with my problem in the main-post. Hope I'm more clearly now

Comment: Can you please run the command;  ip rule list   on HostA and display the output here, also the command
ip route show table OpenVPN

Comment: Please check updated answer, this might fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier. ATM my vpn-provider got some problems as I'm unable to establish a connection to it. I've contacted the support and am waiting now.
The ip routes and ip rules are saved as up/down-skript for the openvpn-connection in order to set them asap the connection is established and unset them again if the connection is gone.